# How to remove blogs?city= in htaccess

Tags: php

I want to remove blogs?city=cityname from url in htaccess mydomain.com/blog/blogs?city=cityname

I had already tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ blog.php?city=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That's unclear. What do you mean by `remove` and when?

Comment: You want visitor to call url like /blog/london and your rewrite rule to redirect to blog.php?city=london ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.php?city=$1 [L]
```

(just one rule, you don't need 2)